# Event plugin problem any one solve .?

Tags: php

bool(false) object(stdClass)#5590 (3) { ["price_struct_id"]=> string(2) "11" ["product_id"]=> string(4) "1294" ["display_order"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: Please have a look at the [Help Center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) on how to ask questions, and what the scope of this comunity is.

Comment: Stop using multiple accounts. I have flagged this and your account.

Comment: sir u hav any idea..?

Answer (score -1):

Hello @bradleysp

When setting up an event for use with GAMP - things have to be done in a very specific order..

To help with this we have produced some How-To videos showing the steps at:

http://opentickets.com/videos

Please can you take a look at the relevant videos to make sure you haven't inadvertently missed out any steps

If you still have problems - we would like you to create an admin WP on the site for us so we can take a look

Please let us know

Chris
Quadshot Tech

https://wordpress.org/plugins/opentickets-community-edition/
pls see the link